# How can I get reference count for a managed object?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, memory-management, reference-counting

.NET profilers can show reference count to managed objects. How do they count them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They use unmanaged APIs which provide access to the profiler.

[ICorProfilerCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230818.aspx) and [ICorProfilerCallback2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230825.aspx) are the main ones. These are the the interfaces that .NET profilers use. There are some more references like [this](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2003/Internals/Profiling.htm).

You can use the methods for class loads (ClassLoadFinished()) and unloads (ClassUnloadFinished()) to track this information.