# Calculate how many references holds a .NET object

Tags: .net

I try to serialize a .NET object.

In one situation, the serialization of that object takes a lot of time. In other, the same serialization of the same (or almost the same) object, goes very quickly...

I try to understand why. I tried to consult the count of "main" object collections, but they displayed me the same result...

I can't manually test ALL the collections counters. I just want to figure out what "part" of my object dramatically changes in "size" before each serialization.

Say, I have a `House`. I the `House` I have `People` collection. I have also `Rooms` collection, `Pets` collection, etc.

I have a lot of actions, `PersonGotOut`, `PetCameIn`, etc. I serialize the object before each action (to be able to Undo-Redo my actions).

After an action, say `PersonChangeRoom` the serialization time grows dramatically, but I see that `Person`'s collection count remains unchanged.

So, my question is how to "detect" such a "object leaks", or how to count how many references or objects "controls" `MyHouse` each time?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471205/how-can-i-get-reference-count-for-a-managed-object

Comment: @Enriqco: No way WHITOUT using external applications like profilers?

Comment: You can use the `ICorProfilerCallback` and `ICorProfilerCallback2` unmanaged interfaces from your code. No need to use an external profiler. They are defined in `CorGuids.lib`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your post correctly, i think then that your conclusion that *leaks are influencing serialization time* is perhaps wrong. let me explain.

.net will only serialize those objects in your object graph, not any orphaned object.

additionally you say the *count of items* in your collections remains the **same**, therefore persistance time should be **linear**.

my only conclusion is that either your serialization code is slow and/or consuming memory to the extent that .NET perhaps is forcing a *garbage collect* (**GC**) to reclaim memory - a very expensive operation.  one can not predict exactly when a GC will occur.  its also frowned upon to force a GC unless the requirement is paramount.  regardless of whether you or .NET invokes the GC, it will still cause your application to freeze whilst the GC is in operation.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two things:

> I serialize the object before each action (to be able to Undo-Redo my actions).

and

> After an action, say PersonChangeRoom the serialization time grows dramatically, but I see that Person's collection count remains unchanged.

I wonder if maybe you are keeping the output of each serialization in memory, as a property of your House object, and this property is one of the items that is serialized. So each time you have any action, this property will grow.  It wouldn't take long for this to become very large.